# For which positive integer $n$, is $\frac{2^n-1}{3}$ a factor of $4m^2+1$ for some integer $m$? (How to prove that one answer group is the only one?)

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

**Edit:**
Dietrich Burde kindly gave me a hint but I, in my inexperience, am not able to understand the logic. I've tried but failed. So, right now my problem is understanding him. So, if you can explain the logic to me, I would be grateful.

For which positive integer $n$, is $\frac{2^n-1}{3}$ a factor of $4m^2+1$ for some integer $m$?
So, I've gotten that $n=2^q,\ q\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ is one solution, and I'm pretty certain that it is the only solution, but I don't know how to prove this (correct or wrong).

If you're interested on how I got to this point, well here's briefly what I've done:
$n$ must be an even integer, as $3\mid 2^n-1$ as $2^{2k}-1=4^k-1\equiv 1^k-1\equiv 0\ (mod\ 3)$

$n=2$ is a quite trivial solution.

$\frac{2^n-1}{3}$ must be a factor of $4m^2+1$, which gives us this (Diophantine) equation: $$4m^2+1=\frac{d(2^n-1)}{3}$$
For $d=1$, we get $4m^2=\frac{2^n-4}{3}$ and because $n$ must be even, we get:
$$4m^2=\frac{4^k-4}{3}$$
$$m^2=\frac{4^{k-1}-1}{3}$$
$$3m^2=(2^{k-1})^2-1^2$$
$$3m^2=(2^{k-1}-1)(2^{k-1}+1)$$
From this you can quite easily get $k=1, m=\pm 1$ as a solution so $n=4$.

But what about for other values of $d$?

Well, we have $n=2,4=2^1, 2^2$. Maybe it works for all $n=2^q$.
I proved this with induction using the fact that $2^{(2^{l+1})}=(2^2)^{2^l}$.

But is there other solutions? I don't know. I feel like there is no other ones because I haven't been able to find anything for the integers in between.

Comment: The question is supposed to say for some $m$. I'll fix it now, sorry! @DietrichBurde

Comment: @DietrichBurde One answer group means that is my answer the only one. I'm really bad at expressing math in English

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: Every divisor $d$ of $4m^2+1$ satisfies $d\equiv 1\bmod 4$. And $\frac{2^n-1}{3}$ is an integer if and only if $n$ is even. Suppose that $n=2k$ is not a power of $2$. Then $\frac{2^n-1}{3}$ has a prime divisor $p$ with $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, a contradiction.

Comment: Would this in itself answer the original question? This seems much more elegant than mine?

Comment: Also can't the divisors be also $3 mod 4$ if there are two of them as $3^2\equiv 1 mod 4$?

Comment: After thinking for a while, it feels like I'm missing something.
a) I don't see why every divisor (and thus prime factor) of $4m^2+1$ is d mod 4 (I know it is but I can't prove it)

b) I don't see the logic that $(n\neq 2^q\wedge p\mid \frac{2^n-1}{3})\Rightarrow p\equiv 3\ \bmod\ 4$. Or even that when it is a power of two that the prime factor would be 1 mod 4.

Comment: For a) see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854445/is-it-possible-that-n21-has-some-divisor-of-the-form-4k3?noredirect=1&lq=1) with $n=2m$. Try to find the others for b) and c) on this site, too.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{4m^2+1}{\frac{2^n-1}{3}}=\frac{3 (4 m^2 + 1)}{(2^n - 1)}$$

This answer does not address the theoretical solutions to this problem but, $-1500\le n \le 1500$ reveals:

$$n=\in\{\pm1,\pm2\}\implies m\in\{\mathbb{Z}-0\}$$
$$
n=\pm 4\implies m\in\{\pm1,\pm4,\pm6,\pm9,\pm11,\pm14,\pm16,\pm19,\cdots\}\\ \text{(OEIS A047209)}$$

$$n=\pm 8
\implies |m|\in\{19,36,49,66,104,121,134,151,\cdots\}$$
$$n=\pm 16
\implies |m|\in\{3606,5646,7461,9501,\cdots\}$$

For $n\in\{32,64,128,\cdots\}$ no solutions were found using $15$-digit precision.

Comment: Well in the range of $n$ there are still solutions like I noted. $n=2,4,8,16,32...$

Comment: Good point, I had quit looking at $n=7$ thinking it was a lost cause. The list will never be complete but, perhaps I can reveal a pattern.

Comment: Yeah, there is a pattern ($n=2^q$) and I think I proved it. The problem I had was to prove that those are the only solutions.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me: I indicated up front that I was not trying to provide "the" answer. I was providing empirical data to support any "theory" provided by others. I thought this was useful. If anyone disagrees, please let me know why it was not useful. Thanks